# Can't use variable in date

Tags: linux, bash, shell, date

I'm trying to convert a string into seconds using date +%s, but everytime i get this error:

```
deadline='Monday August 2 10:45:25 AM GMT' 
date -d $deadline +%s
date: extra operand'2'
```

But if I don't use a variable this command works fine

```
date -d 'Monday August 2 10:45:25 AM GMT' +%s
1627901012
```

Can somebody explain why this command doesn't work with my variable?

Comment: You need to quote your variable, `"$deadline"`.

Answer (score 0):

> why this command doesn't work with my variable?

Unquoted variable expansions undergo word splitting.

After expansion, you are executing:

```
date -d Monday August 2 10:45:25 AM GMT +%s
```

`Monday` is the argument for `-d`, `August` is the one argument that `date` takes. Then the rest `August 2 10:...` are just invalid positional arguments for `date`, so the tool exits with an error that too many arguments were passed.